# Error posting data

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Hello I have the following piece of code and it won't post the data when I click the submit button. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Login

```
<link href="/owen/less/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" />
<script src="/owen/js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="/login/" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />

                        <label for="email">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />

                        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Could you add your view code?

Comment: @laundroMat I would but I can see in firebug that nothing is getting posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form data uses `name`, not `id`. You must give the form controls `name` attributes to be used in the data that is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/. Are you missing the middleware setting or RequestContext?